# How to use update function for caph list on Tizen?

Tags: jquery, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, caph-framework

I'm following the documentation here : http://developer.samsung.com/onlinedocs/tv/caphdocs/main.html?type=jquery&doc=tutorial&p1=8

I have this in my contentList.html file :

```
    <div class="list-container">
        <div id="list1"></div> 
    </div>
```

In my contentList.js file, in the window.onLoad function I have the following:

```
$('#list1').caphList({
        items: listOfSeries,
        template: '<div class="item" focusable><div style= "width:100%; height:100%"></div><%= item.title %></div>',
        containerClass : 'list',
        direction: 'vertical'
    });
var contentListView = $('#list1')[0].caphList;
```

where listOfSeries is a global variable defined as an empty array. I have a button that, when pressed, sends a GET request to a server to get a list of tv show series. I then want to update the list by calling contentListView.update() once I have populated listOfSeries. However, I get an error saying:

cannot read property 'update' of undefined.

I'm fairly new to web development so I'm sorry if this is a noob question but how do I update this content list?

EDIT:

Here is my contentList.js file

```
var globalUrl = "";
var contentListRequestAttempts;
var listOfSeries = [""];

window.onload = function () {

    /*$(".contentListButton").caphButton({
        onFocused : function(event, originalEvent){
            $(event.currentTarget).css({
                "border" : "3px solid red",
                "height" : "50px",
                "font-size" : "40px"
            });
        },
        onBlurred : function(event, originalEvent){
            $(event.currentTarget).css({
                "border" : "3px solid transparent",
                "height" : "50px",
                "font-size" : "40px"
            });
        },
        focusOption: {

        },
        toggle : false,
        onSelected : function(event, originalEvent){
            contentListRequestAttempts = 0;
            requestContentList();
        }
    }); */


    $('#list1').caphList({
        items: listOfSeries,
        template: '<div class="item" focusable><div style= "width:100%; height:100%"></div><%= item.title %></div>',
        containerClass : 'list',
        direction: 'vertical'
    });
    var contentListView = $('#list1')[0].caphList;
    contentListRequestAttempts = 0;
    requestContentList(contentListView);

}

function requestContentList(contentListView){
    console.log("Send Content List Request- Attempt#"+contentListRequestAttempts);
    globalUrl = localStorage.getItem("serverUrl");
    var getContentListUrl = globalUrl + "/client/v1/content";

    console.log("Get content list url:" + getContentListUrl);

    $.ajax({
        url: getContentListUrl,
        type: 'GET',
        success: function(result){
            var parsed = JSON.parse(result);
            console.log(parsed);

            var numberOfSeries = parsed.DfwWebClient.recordings.length;

            // Check if response contains recordings up to 10 times
            if(contentListRequestAttempts < 10){
                if(numberOfSeries === 0){
                    //If content list is not ready yet, wait half sec before requesting content list again
                    contentListRequestAttempts++;
                    wait(500);
                    requestContentList();
                } else {                
                    parseRecordings(parsed, contentListView);
                }       
            } else {
                alert("No Content Found");
            }               
        },
        error: function(xhr,status,error){
            alert("Server not found. Please ensure server is enabled, and that the IP address entered is correct.");
        }
    }); 
}

function parseRecordings(jsonResponse,contentListView){
    var numberOfSeries = jsonResponse.DfwWebClient.recordings.length;
    console.log("Number of Series: "+numberOfSeries);

    listOfSeries= new Array(numberOfSeries);
    var i;
    for(i=0; i < numberOfSeries; i++){
        listOfSeries[i] = jsonResponse.DfwWebClient.recordings[i];
    }
    console.log(listOfSeries);

    /*var items = listOfSeries;*/

/*  $('#list1').caphList({
        items: listOfSeries,
        template: '<div class="item" focusable><div style= "width:100%; height:100%"></div><%= item.title %></div>',
        containerClass : 'list',
        direction: 'vertical',
        onFocusItemView: function(context) {
            //console.log('focus', context);
        }
    });*/

    //contentListView.reload();
    contentListView.update();
}

function wait(ms){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var end = start;
    while (end < start + ms){
        end = new Date().getTime();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the code section where you are calling the update method. The problem seems to be that you are not accessing the caphList properly, not the update method.

Comment: Edited my question

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a caphList with zero elements at the beginning, that's why you are probably getting the error.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and let you know. Also, any idea why the first entry in my list is always blank? I could post another question for it but thought I'd ask you first. Essentially, when I display the Caph list, the first entry in my list is empty. Let's say my array contains "Apple","Ball" and "Candy". When I display the list, it comes out as <blank spot>, "Apple", "Ball" and "Candy" but if I press Enter on the first entry, it registers it as a click on the "Apple" entry. I have searched up and down my code but I can't find out why it's doing this

Comment: The reason might be this statement: var listOfSeries = [""]; Try var listOfSeries = []; instead.

Comment: Have you found the solution?